# Use Django User permission layout for other manytomany field

Tags: python, django

When in a User object in the Django Admin, there is a really nice way to add permissions to the user.

[image]

For a completely different model, I would like to use the same system. This model has a manytomany field to another model. Is there a way to copy the layout of the user admin, to this model's admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your field to the [`ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options)'s [`filter_horizontal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal):

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    filter_horizontal = ['my_many_to_many_field']
```